# because reloading the page deletes the vuex data, having used mutations, vuejs?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

Currently I have the following configuration in my vuex, what I do is through the userAuth action verify the user's role and assign it to a property of the state `'rol_user'`, using the `UPDATEROL` mutation. I execute this action when I log in so that the user's role is recorded in vuex.

here the vuex configuration:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import firebase from 'firebase';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        rol_user: ''
    },
    mutations: {
        UPDATEROL: function (state, payload) {
            state.rol_user = payload.rol_user;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        userAuth: async (context) =>{
            let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            if(user){
                let user_info = await firebase.database().ref('users').child(user.uid).once('value');
                let val_user = user_info.val();
                console.log("USER AUTH - VUEX");
                console.log(val_user.rol);
                context.commit('UPDATEROL',{
                    rol_user: val_user.rol
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It effectively assigns the user's role to the `state` property, `rol_user`.
The problem I have is when reloading the page. When I reload the page `rol_user` returns to its initial state, that is empty.
How can I do so that the value of the role is not lost even when reloading the page, but rather that it is changed to empty only until I log out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some sort of storage mechanism and check that storage everytime the app is first mounted. For example, you could store a session key in `localStorage` or just store the user state that you want to persist.

Note, I do not know what kind of data you are storing, I am assuming `rol_user` is an object, if it is a string, you do not need JSON serialization/deserialization as I've done in the example below:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import firebase from 'firebase';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        rol_user: ''
    },
    mutations: {
        UPDATEROL: function (state, payload) {
            state.rol_user = payload.rol_user;
            localStorage && (localStorage.rol_user = JSON.stringify(state.rol_user)); 
               //^ try to store the user role in localStorage
        },

    },
    actions: {
        userAuth: async (context) =>{
            if(localStorage && localStorage.rol_user) { 
               //^ if it's in localStorage, log the user back in/update state to match what it is in localStorage
                 context.commit('UPDATEROL', { rol_user: JSON.parse(localStorage.rol_user)});
                 return;
            }
            let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            if(user){
                let user_info = await firebase.database().ref('users').child(user.uid).once('value');
                let val_user = user_info.val();
                console.log("USER AUTH - VUEX");
                console.log(val_user.rol);
                context.commit('UPDATEROL',{
                    rol_user: val_user.rol
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You could also use Cookies (cookies are generally more common for this purpose, but localStorage also works just fine)

Comment: rol_user contains a string, either '1', '2' or '3'

Comment: @JG_GJ Then you can skip using `JSON.stringify`/`JSON.parse`. It should work fine with or without it, it's just not necessary if it's already a string.

Comment: I understand and in my log out how should I go?

Comment: `localStorage.rol_user = undefined`

Comment: I understand, if I see that when I log out and log in with another user who has a different role, it shows the role of the user that started earlier

Comment: If you set `localStorage.rol_user` to undefined and refresh the page you should be logged out again. If you login, then login again, it will indeed show the previous user role. You need to ensure that before a second login happens the first logout occurs, and you need to ensure that with every logout `localStorage.rol_user=undefined` is executed.

Comment: I have refreshed the page and indeed rol_user in localstorage remains but in my vuex no. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the support

Comment: Are you calling `$store.dispatch('userAuth')`? You do still need to dispatch the `userAuth` action when the page is refreshed.

Comment: $ store.dispatch ('userAuth') I only do it in the component where I login. In my case, how should I add it when it comes to cooling? Should it be in a mounted component that finds me when it comes to cooling?

Comment: @JG_GJ I mean, you can put the code to restore the data from `localStorage` wherever you want, I just put it in `userAuth`, you can either dispatch `userAuth` as soon as the app is mounted or you can take the `localStorage` code out of `userAuth` and put it in your app start up code

Comment: I understand, I am having the inconvenience that the value of vuex is using it in a directive, so the problem is that it first loads the directive and then in the directive it shows the value that rol_user previously had